# Flow generation option that will create separate flow files per sub-flow?

Tags: origen-sdk

I use [sub-flows](https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/flows/#Re-usable_Flow_Snippets) extensively and would like to have an option to generate a separate ATE flow file per sub-flow (e.g. on V93K a separate .tf file).  Is this possible?  Perhaps something like this, wih the default being the current behavior:

```
import :my_subflow, generate_standalone: true
```

The reason this is valuable is that we use a test program assembler that can merge multiple flow files together given a sequence of flow files.  This saves on test program load time for debug sessions.

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no switch like that currently, but note that you can generate sub-flows directly:

```
origen p program/_my_subflow.rb
```

The leading "_" in the name means that they will be not be generated as standalone flows if you point the program generator to the directory (`origen p program/`), but if you explicitly ask it to generate that file then it will.

Comment: so generating the sub-flow files directly will only work for flow with no options being passed from another flow file right?  Do you see value in adding the ability to generate separate .tf files via an `import` option?

Comment: Yeah, good point. I could imagine adding the ability to supply options via the command line, but that's not possible today either.
I don't personally see value in this feature, but I would support either route if someone wants to work on it.